# new File ( path ) always says that there is no file

Tags: java, android, file, path, soundpool

my problem is a little bit tricky to describe.

I have a separated resources folder in my project (and in the apk-file).

```
String path = "/resources/instruments/data/bongo/audio/bong1.wav";
```

I can already use it with

```
url = StreamHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResource( path );
url.openStream();
```

but actually I want to load the file into the SoundPool.
I tried it this way:

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(  5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0 );  
soundPool.load ( path, 1 );
```

... but i always get an error information: "error loading /resourc..."

[load(String path, int )](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/media/SoundPool.java#SoundPool.load%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29)
On this link I've seen that I need the correct path for File

```
File file = new File( path );
if( file.exists() ) 
     //always false but i thing if it would be true soundPool.load should work too
```

Now my question: how has the path to be that it works. Or is there any other idea for my problem (p.e. with the AssetManager) ?

Btw. I know that there are special Android ways to get resources like R.id.View ... but in my case it would be not easy to handle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I don't see WAV files as 'resources' and I'd suggest you put them in the 'assets' folder and use AssetManager as you mentioned.

This works for me...

Create a folder structure in your project...

```
    /assets/instruments/data/bongo/audio
```

...then copy your bong1.wav file there.

Use the following to load it. NOTE: DO NOT put '/' in front of 'instruments' when supplying the path to soundPool.load()...

```
    // Declare globally if needed
    int mySoundId;
    SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0 );
    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

    //Use in whatever method is used to load the sounds
    try {
        mySoundId = soundPool.load(am.openFd("instruments/data/bongo/audio/bong1.wav"), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Use this to play it...

```
    soundPool.play(mySoundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently expecting a file system path rather than a classpath path.

Use [`URL#getPath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29) to obtain it.

```
soundPool.load(url.getPath());
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. I don't know why but resource still isn't found. It's a pity because it would be so much easier :)